# JQuery removeCookie not working on Internet Explorer 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies

I have the following snippet of code

```
jQuery.removeCookie("foo", { path: '/foo' });
```

Which works fine in chrome, but in IE the cookie isn't removed. When I inspect the cookies in chrome, I can see it is under path */foo*. I have tried the following call also with a trailing slash on the path, and with no option argument at all, but don't get it working in IE.

How to remove cookies in IE?

Comment: When you say "I see it under path `/foo`" do you mean the cookie path or the page URL? Which jQuery cookie library are you using?

Comment: I mean the path mentioned in the chrome cookie window. JSESSIONID for example has a path '/'. I'm using *jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.4.0*. The library implementation to remove the cookie is following `$.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
                if ($.cookie(key) === undefined) {
                        return false;
                }

                // Must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
                $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, { expires: -1 }));
                return !$.cookie(key);
        };`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your jQuery version, this usually works:

```
$.cookie("name", null, { path: '/' });
```